# exe created complains about ImportError: no module named pytz

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe, pytz

I have created a python executable using py2exe. When I run the exe then I get the following error:

```
I:\YYY\dist>gui.exe   
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "gui.py", line 31, in <module>   
ImportError: No module named pytz
```

But, in the python interpreter I can import pytz without any problem.

```
I:\YYY\dist>python  
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32  
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.  
>>> import pytz   
>>>
```

Any help to resolve the above issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Call setup() with following option:

```
setup(..., options={
    'py2exe': {
        'packages': [
            'pytz',
        ],
    },
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. After the mod to the 'setup.py' as suggested the exe creation itself fails. The stack trace is too long to add here. Here are few lines from the stack trace:  

I:\XXX>python setup.py py2exe
running py2exe
...   
  File "setup.py", line 6, in <module>  
    'packages':['pytz']  
  File "e:\Install\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup  
    dist.run_commands()  
.....  
  File "e:\Install\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 204, in find_head_package  
    raise ImportError, "No module named " + qname  
ImportError: No module named pytz

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python?

Comment: From what I can make out I have 'python 2.7.5'. Is there a surefire way to ensure only version of python is on my host?